# TAPi18n: how to construct the key to be translated dynamically?

Tags: meteor, internationalization

I'm trying to add a prefix to the keys to be translated. This is one of my attempts:

```
<label for="{{n}}">{{_ 'input_label_{{n}}' }}</label>
<input name="{{n}}" placeholder="{{_ 'input_placeholder_{{n}}' }}">
```

Obviously it does not work because you can't nest {{ ... }}'s.

I've also tried creating a helper:

```
{{tr 'input_label' n}}

tr: function(prefix, fieldName) {
  return TAPi18next.t(prefix + '_' + fieldName);
}
```

But it comes back untranslated. I assume because I'm calling TAPi18n as a static and not an instance of it, but I don't know how else to do it.

These are just two of many attempts.

I will have hundreds of inputs, and I want to avoid sending all the translation keys to the input template, since it's redundant information. The key variations can easily be made by adding prefixes.

Can you think of any way to generate the key values dynamically?

Comment: In your helper attempt, is TAPi18next.t not getting called, or is it returning the wrong thing?

Comment: It could be a reactivity problem, maybe the current language isn't loaded when the template is first rendered, and `TAPi18next.t` is non-reactive. You could try `TAPi18n.__` (that's two underscores) which the documentation promises is reactive.

Comment: Thanks. It does return something: the argument unmodified. When I try with TAPi18n__() I get a "Exception in template helper: TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: No, you are right! It works! I had tried with TAPi18next.__(), not with TAPi18n.__(). If you enter that as a response I can mark it as answered :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second approach, but with `TAPi18n.__` rather than `TAPi18next.t`.

Unlike `TAPi18next.t`, `TAPi18n.__` reactively updates when the user's language choice is changed and the language has finished downloading. I'm guessing the problem is that the language choice hasn't quite come through when the template is first rendered, so `TAP18next.t` returns the strings in the default language (English), and doesn't update when the language changes. Using `TAPi18n.__` instead fixes this.